# Corda: Possible Latency issue with encumbered tokens

Tags: corda

We are running into a possible latency issue with Corda Token SDK and encumbrances. The encumbrance is not immediately recognized by DatabaseTokenSelection but after a sufficient wait it does. And this happens sporadically.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hard to diagnose but if you're able to pinpoint what's causing the latency please do make an issue on here: https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc

if you don't hear back on the issue message me (@david) on slack.corda.net I can help kick the can along for you.

Some tips for how to debug this:

- test the latency between the nodes with ping
- make sure any cnames resolve with nslookup from some of your corda nodes
- check if any flows are ending up in the flow hospital along the way: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/node-flow-hospital.html